# How to hide json by pressing button?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

So, I want to make two buttons one for showing json data (animals-1.json,animals-2.json animals-3.json, ... it depends of pageCounter which is working fine) and second button for deleting first showed json on screen. Every json has only one number written for example animals-1.json shows number 1, animals-2.json shows number 2 and so on... so when first button is clicked SHOW 3 times it will show on screen numbers 1 2 3 and when I click second button HIDE I want first number to dissapear and show on screen only numbers 2 3 (animals-2.json and animals-3.json). How to do this? Thanks :)
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h2>next is</h2>
<button id="btn">SHOW</button>
<button id="btnn" >HIDE</button>
<div id="animal-info"></div>
<div id="nome"></div>
<script src="skripta.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
 var pageCounter = 1;
   
    var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");
    
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var btnn = document.getElementById("btnn");
    
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET','http://10.0.9.243/animals-'+ pageCounter + '.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      renderHTML(ourData);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
    pageCounter++;
    });
    
    function renderHTML(data) {
    var htmlString  = "";
    for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
      htmlString += "<p>" + data[i].name +  "</p>"
    }
    animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Don't use screenshots and past your code instead. Also take a look how to create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is adding the class name in htmlString elements.

```js
function renderHTML(data) {
var htmlString  = document.createElement("div");
for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  let pText = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
  let pElement = document.createElement("p");
  pElement.append(pText);
  htmlString.append(pElement);
  htmlString.classList.add('containers') // new Line added
  }
animalContainer.append(htmlString);
}

btnn.addEventListener("click", function(){
let containers = document.getElementsByClassName('containers');
if(containers.length > 0){
    containers[0].remove();
}
  });
```

Comment: Your code is missing several equal signs for some reason.

Comment: The OP upload a screenshot of his code, I had to write all his code, however, the code that I added (check for comments) should work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to show first with button SHOW few json files and then clicking on HIDE button delete always first. For example I showed 1 2 3 4 and clicked hide button once then is showed 2 3 4 clicking it again we have got 3 4 showed

Comment: I've edited the code, it should work now like you want, I changed the way of appending the elements created to parents.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! You made my day :)